# Is there a way to change width direction in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Currently in Flutter, when you change width via animation, there is a direction of width scaling. For example if you just add width tween, your object will widen to the left. If you change offset to minus - still left, but if you change offset to plus, it would widen itself to the right.

My question is can you change the direction the object widens without changing the object offset?

Comment: did you try on `tween` `1-0` , or using `transform`

Comment: I have tried using transform, tried scaling, rotating and whatnot...
What do you mean by tween 1-0?

Comment: tween began:1 and end: 0

Comment: It would not work because I need the object to grow from 0 to x and then widen from x to y. I think I am going to try with bezier paths, but thank you for your help